# Making the user store audio in another object

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm trying to do this thing where the user can put sounds inside images.
The user can press a button that plays a sound and then after pressing that button they click on an image and then the image now contains that sound, making it a new sound button. (Illustrated with the images below, take note the shapes on top are map areas)

What's the best way to go about this? A professor recommended me some lines of code, but it didn't work. Here's a very simplified version of my code:

```
        <div class="buttons">
        <audio id="c1" src="notes/c1.wav" preload="auto"></audio>
        <button id="audio1" onclick="document.getElementById('c1').play();" data-file="notes/c1.wav" data-state>A1</button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="canvas"><img src="images\60.jpg" alt="image" usemap="#image-map" class="map"></div>
    <map name="image-map">
        <area id="shape" alt="bbs" href="#" coords="638,310,999,565,807,784,485,541" shape="poly"></map>
   //this is the script he sent me
    <script>
        let audio_file= null
        let storage= sessionStorage
    
        document.querySelector('#audio1').addEventListener('click', evt => {audio_file = event.target.dataset.file});
        document.querySelector('#shape').addEventListener('click', evt => {storage.setItem('shape', audio_file)});
    </script>
```

Basically, I want the user to click the #C1 button and then click the #shape area so the audio file in #C1 will be stored in #shape.

I don't have to use the professor's code, so any alternative or suggestion will do. Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly: click sound button --> sound is played --> click image -->  image becomes sound button for that sound --> settings are reset or clicking more images adds more buttons?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes, pretty much what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Press a button that plays a sound and then after pressing that button click on an image and then the image now contains that sound

```js
let currentSound = null

function trySound(e) {
  const isSoundChanging = currentSound != null
  if (isSoundChanging) {
    assignSound(e.target)
  } else {
    playSound(e.target.dataset.sound)
  }
}

function activateSound(audioID) {
  playSound(audioID)
  currentSound = audioID
}

function playSound(audioID) {
  const isValidID = (audioID ?? '').length > 1
  if (!isValidID) return

  const audioElement = document.getElementById(audioID)
  audioElement.currentTime = 0;
  audioElement.play();
}

function assignSound(image) {
  image.dataset.sound = currentSound
  playSound(currentSound)
  currentSound = null
}
```

```css
button {
  all: unset;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  background-color: magenta;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}
button:hover,
img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:active,
img:active {
  transform: scale(0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <audio id="c1" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/209/209513_3916239-lq.mp3" preload="auto">Audio could not load</audio>
  <button id="audio1" onclick="activateSound('c1')">A1</button>
  <audio id="c2" src="https://freesound.org/data/previews/146/146058_529852-lq.mp3" preload="auto">Audio could not load</audio>
  <button id="audio1" onclick="activateSound('c2')">A2</button>
</div>

<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100" width=100 height=100 alt="random image 1" onclick="trySound(event)" />
<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/101x101" width=101 height=101 alt="random image 2" onclick="trySound(event)" />
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting a complete answer, but this works! Thank you!

Comment: @Shawrk You're welcome. Please mark as answer and improve the question